# Выделение запятыми оборота "при необходимости"

Tags: пунктуация

Не можем определиться, нужно ли в следующем предложении выделять запятыми оборот "при необходимости":

> В поле "Бонусные баллы" введите(,) при необходимости(,) новую стоимость пакета в бонусных баллах.

С одной стороны, на схожий вопрос есть ответ справочной службы "Грамота.ру": "Cочетание "при необходимости" вводным не является, выделять запятыми его не следует" (http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/29_317702 ).

С другой стороны, предложение эквивалентно следующему предложению:
В поле "Бонусные баллы" введите, в случае необходимости, новую стоимость пакета в бонусных баллах. И в этом случае запятая явно нужна.

Comment: Антон, ваша ссылка не открывается.

Comment: Извините, в ссылку затянуло скобку с точкой. Поправил.
http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/29_317702

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы.
Как стало понятно, возможно двоякое написание, в нашем конкретном случае все-таки используем выделение запятыми — у нас имеет место интоннационное выделение.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для смыслового выделения или только попутного пояснения в художественной речи **могут** обособляться обстоятельства, выраженные именами ***существительными в косвенных падежах с предлогами*** и стоящие в середине или в конце предложения, например: Видно, и Чичиковы, **на несколько минут в жизни,** обращаются в поэтов... (Гоголь); ...Я отстал немного, потом, **с помощью хлыста и ног,** разогнал свою лошадку (Л. Толстой); И потом он встречал ее в Городском саду и на сквере, **по нескольку раз в день** (Чехов); Утром проснулся он рано, **с головной болью,** разбуженный шумом... (Чехов); И тишина, **от времени,** становилась все зловещей (Горький)[Здесь](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm)

В предложениях возможна двоякая постановка знаков в зависимости от интонации.

Answer (score 3):

Странно. Я писал, но мой ответ исчез.

***Вопрос 6160:***    Очень часто в документах, с которыми мне приходится работать, встречается словосочетание "при необходимости". Нужно ли выделять его запятыми и чем оно является в предложении (вводным словосочетанием или обособленным обстоятельством)?
1) Наличие(,) при необходимости(,) соответствующих лицензий для участия в работе по созданию...дает право...
2) Сведения о выборе конкретного поставщика отражаются в протоколе комиссии и(,) при необходимости(,) размещаются на сайте организации.

***Ответ:*********(Грамма.ру***)***   Сочетание «при необходимости» относится к разряду синтаксических единиц, которые, в зависимости от коммуникативных задач говорящего, в предложении могут играть роль или обычного второстепенного члена предложения (обстоятельства), или обособленного оборота (обособленного обстоятельства) со всеми присущими им признаками: смысловой нагрузкой дополнительного сообщения и интонационным (в устном исполнении) и пунктуационным (на письме) выделением. Если «при необходимости» обособлено, то его смысловой план примерно тот же, что и у придаточного предложения «если это необходимо». Второе предложение идеально подходит для упражнения «или так, или так». Если в нем оборот «при необходимости» не выделен, то делаем вывод о том, что оно служит для передачи двух сообщений: 1) Сведения о выборе конкретного поставщика отражаются в протоколе комиссии; 2) (сведения) при необходимости размещаются на сайте организации. В случае обособления сообщений в предложении не два, а три: 1) Сведения о выборе конкретного поставщика отражаются в протоколе комиссии; 2) (сведения) размещаются на сайте организации; 3) делается это в необходимых случаях. Ясно, что обособление подчеркивает это условие – при необходимости – и читателю ничего не остается, как разгадать загадку автора, ответив на вопрос, зачем ему это выделение было нужно. Первое предложение комментировать не беремся, потому что не совсем ясно, почему в нем идет речь о лицензиях, которые дают право, а между тем сочетание «при необходимости» весь этот реальный план сводит к нулю…

Answer (score 2):

Я сейчас не могу посмотреть в источники, но насколько понимаю, в обоих случаях обособление опционально. Замена "при необходимости" на "в случае необходимости" ничего принципиального или "явно нужного" не добавляет. Вводными эти сочетания, как понимаю, не являются, но для удобочитаемости в определенном контексте могут быть обособлены.

Я бы обошелся без запятых в обоих случаях.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ.

По поводу оборота "в случае необходимости" я ориентировался на справочник по пунктуации (http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_121).

Также нашел на ресурсе схожий вопрос:
http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/5104#5118, тут мнение обратное, но тоже неоднозначное.

У нас с коллегой, собственно, как раз спор с этими двумя полюсами, хочется, чтобы его кто-то однозначно решил. ☺