# Нужна ли запятая после слов "при необходимости"?

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно я понял, что в предложении

"*Наши специалисты выполнят замену пластиковых окон за 2 часа. При необходимости помоют после себя окна и полы*"

запятая после "*при необходимости*" не ставится?

Comment: Это комментарий фразы, возможно, и не вашего сочинения. ==== Не «после себя» (простореч.), а «по завершении работ». Не «окна», поскольку окна старые меняют на окна новые, готовые к эксплуатации,  т. е. не грязные. И не «полы», с окнами никак не связанные. А «место установки».

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выделение запятыми оборота "при необходимости"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/42822/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8)

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна, это обычный член предложения - обстоятельство.